# Moving <httpredirect> out of web.config in separate config file

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, http-redirect

We have many (more than 100) redirects in our web.config like

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
         <add wildcard="/a" destination="/a/dfdf/default.htm" />
         <add wildcard="/sad" destination="/aasd/dfdf/defsadault.htm" />
         <add wildcard="/asdsaa" destination="/aasdas/dfasddf/default.htm" />
         <add wildcard="/aasdsa" destination="/asdsaa/dfdf/defsdault.htm" />
         <add wildcard="/aasd" destination="/adsa/dfdf/default.htm" />
..... more than 100
      </httpRedirect>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Is there way we can have this  section managed in separate web.config or any other best solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can move some config elements into their own config file to reduce clutter in the web.config.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect configSource="httpRedirects.config" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is achieved by adding the configSource attribute as shown above.

And in your seperate httpRedirects.config

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
     <add wildcard="/a" destination="/a/dfdf/default.htm" />
     <add wildcard="/sad" destination="/aasd/dfdf/defsadault.htm" />
     <add wildcard="/asdsaa" destination="/aasdas/dfasddf/default.htm" />
     <add wildcard="/aasdsa" destination="/asdsaa/dfdf/defsdault.htm" />
     <add wildcard="/aasd" destination="/adsa/dfdf/default.htm" />
</httpRedirect>
```

Note I have only tried this with other config elements.

Comment: @vikaskumar do the httpRedirect attributes (especially enabled="true") appear in your external config file ?

Comment: It was not there and it worked after adding same to external file. thank you

Comment: This doesn't work, I get the error "configSource must exist alone in an element "

Answer (score 1):

You can store that in Separate Config file as shown here: [SectionInformation.ConfigSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx)

In order to avoid cluttering the configuration file - `web.config` - it can be defined in a separate configuration file. That file can then be referenced from the web.config file as below:

```
<httpRedirect configSource="httpRedirects.config" />
```

The `configSource` attribute tells IIS configuration that the `<httpRedirect>` section is defined in a separate file `httpRedirects.config`.

EDIT:

Please make sure you have httpRedirect attribute set to `enabled=true` as ***the default value is false.***

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" configSource="httpRedirects.config" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get the error *"configSource must exist alone in an element"*