# Placing web.config redirects in a seperate file

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

[The following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360462/moving-httpredirect-out-of-web-config-in-separate-config-file) claims it's possible to place all web.config httpRedirect in a separate file however when I follow the instructions in the post I get:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
Config Error    configSource must exist alone in an element
```

What my web.config looks like:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" configSource="WebRedirects.config" ></httpRedirect>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What my WebRedirects.config looks like (obviously the dots represent multiple entries):

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent">
     <add wildcard="/folder/file.aspx" destination="/another-folder/another-file.aspx" />
     .
     .
     .
</httpRedirect>
```

Answer (score 0):

Argh, I saw the problem as soon as I posted it. Needed to remove the `enable="true"` attribute. So it becomes:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect configSource="WebRedirects.config" ></httpRedirect>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```